# how to implement a counter with AngularJS inside a ng-repeat?

Tags: css, angularjs, counter

I've got an app, where I get a bunch of data from the API, this data rapresents activities done on a given
day in a given month, and they are displayed in a table.

I can have different tables (let s say one for working activities, one for school and so on).

In the tables, `<TH>` are the days of the month, and the first TD of each row is the month.
The table only generates a row for any given month only if there is data in that month.

A first ng-repeat will create X number of tables depending on the different activities, and 
a second nested ng-repeat will fill the rows of the table for the months with data in it.

Everything works fine, but I have an issue. 
There is a specific print view for these tables, before it was one table per page (I used a css rule to break page after every table)

but now I wanna implement something better, as a table could have only one row 
(let s say you have activities only in january, and none in other months)
it's pretty ugly when it breaks the page and prints just one table with one row in a new page.

So I wanna implement a counter that let's say after 15 rows it will break the page.

By 15 rows I mean global rows, so it could be a full table with 12 rows (12 months with data) followed 
by a table with 3rows only, and then it would break page for the next table.

What's the best way to achieve something like this in angularJS?

with: `p.presences.length`  I get in return the number of months each table in the ng-repeat will have.

So my idea is to have a counter that adds `p.presences.length` at each iteration of the ng-repeat, then I would use that counter in a ng-class to break the page,

Currently to break pages I'm using this code:

```
<div class="breakPagePrint" ng-class="p.print ? 'showTablePrint' : 'noDisplay'"> </div>
```

with this css code:

```
.breakPagePrint {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

`p.print` is a Boolean that is given by a checkbox on every table, so if the user wants a given table to be included in the print page, he ll check the box.

so my idea is to put in this ng-class an expression with the counter, something like

```
ng-class= "tableCounter > 15 && p.print ? 'showTablePrint' : 'noDisplay'"
```

but in this case the counter should get reset after 15 otherwise it won't break page again after another 15counts (at 30).

If anyone has some ideas on how to nicely implement a counter and how to use it at best in my case.

Thank you

Comment: You should put such kind of logic into your component or controller. Don't handle your counters in your view.

Comment: (_nice essay_) tl;dr: Have you tried using `$index`? It's a built-in iterator for `ng-repeat`

Comment: It would be good if you create plunker with some sample code to help you.

Comment: as I never put a counter before in angularJS, I m looking for tips, I have nothing against putting it in the controller, just looking for the smartest way to achieve what I m trying to do here

to Aleksey, how would $index help me? how could I use it in my case?

Comment: I don't know what sample code to show, as all the rest of the code is irrelevant, I can access the number or row each table will have, and I wrote the code for it, and I want that after X amount of rows I get a page-break, 

IF you think some specific code could help let me know, but I think I put everything needed for this problem

Comment: @AJ989 I was saying if you are iterating through items in `ng-repeat` and you want to change the CSS after a certain index/counter value, then you can simply use `$index`. Here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/QT1GeEUEcig2ptvNQARe?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$index` of your ng-repeat to check to see when it has covered a multiple 15 records or use the `p.presences.length` if that gives the property you need (i.e. the counter for each row). Then insert the div at each multiple.

Assuming your `div` above currently works (but only for 15 at the moment) then just add the following code to that `div`. This uses the modulus of 15.

```
<div ng-class="{'breakPagePrint':(p.presences.length%15==0),'noDisplay':(p.presences.length%15!=0)}"></div>
```

(I'm para-coding so not 100% sure of the syntax) But give that a try and see if it works. But basically it adds the breaking div whenever the `p.presences.length` is a multiple of 15, or every 15 records.

Comment: thank you for the answer! My code above is not working, that was an idea!

The main issue with p.presences.length is that it returns the value of the number of rows in a table, but it isnt cumulative! meaning that in one iteration it can return 3, and in the next 6, if the table in the first iteration has 3 rows, and in the second it has 6! 

I need a counter that after 15 GLOBAL rows changes the class with ng-class! 
your idea would work If I manage somehow to store in a variable all the p.presences.length sums for each iteration, and then use it with the ng-class with the modulus of 15!

Comment: So if `p.presences.length` doesn't work use `$index` instead. That is the internal counter on the repeat.